# How can I see the source code on a suggested edit review page?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, markdown, rejected-edits

How can I see the source code on a suggested edit review page?

I want a similar thing as in [this link](https://serverfault.com/revisions/f555d609-a538-4ed2-ab89-644c6ddf183f/view-source) for [this suggested edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/381047).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can click the 'markdown' link to see what has been edited:

[image]

You'll need to combine that (manually) with the source code of the revision the edit was suggested to, if you want the *complete* source code of the suggested edit. An approved or improved edit will show up in the revision list; this 'trick' is only necessary for rejected edits.

I tried to find a way to obtain the source with the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-by-ids), but

1. that returns the rendered body
2. the suggested edit IDs used by the API are different from the ones you see in the URL.

Another option would be to wait until next Sunday and fetch the `Text` from the `SuggestedEdits` table in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). However, it's complicated (impossible?) to correctly fetch the whitespace.